# How to distribute a support build from android app bundle?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, android-app-signing

The end goal is to collect application logs from problematic devices of users who post reviews in Play Store. This is achieved by sending a support build (release build with logs) to such users and asking them to reproduce an issue and send logs.

**APK signing (OK)**

When classic signing scheme (without android app bundles) is used, steps are as follows

- generate release and support apks and sign them with the same key
- upload release apk to Play Store
- upload support apk to a cloud and provide a downloadable link to it

User can now download a support build by a link and **install it over release version** from market. When new version is available in Play Store, user can successfully **update support build** to that version.

**Google signing (FAIL)**

With android app bundles signing, I tried the following

- generate release app bundle and sign it with **upload key**
- upload release app bundle to Play Store
- generate support apk and sign it with the same **upload key**
- upload support apk to a cloud and provide a downloadable link to it

⚠️ However, users cannot install support build over release build from Play Store, because **release build is re-signed by Google** (signatures do not match).

I tried to solve this in following ways

- a. Sign support apk with the same key that Google uses to sign release bundle.

  FAIL: Cannot find the way to download the Google key.
- b. Upload support bundle and let Google sign it. Download signed support apk from Play Console.

  FAIL: Can only download a set of apks for a specific device. Cannot install them manually.
- c. Use Internal app sharing. Upload support bundle and copy a download link.

  FAIL: apks for internal sharing are signed with a different key - signatures do not match

My questions

1. Is there another way to achieve the end goal (get logs from market users)?
2. Do I miss something in my attempts I mentioned above? Specifically,

- is it possible to download a real signing key from Play Console?
- is it possible for an average user to install a set of apks generated from an app bundle?

Answer (score 2):

Re-using the same **upload key** does not mean that Google will re-sign the APK with the same **app signing key**.

If you want the support APK to be signed with the same key as your main app, you need to request it explicitly when you enroll in App Signing by Play:

[image: Manage preferences]

[image: Reuse key of another app]

To answer your other questions:

- It is not possible to download the signing key from Google Play.
- The best way for an average user to download APKs generated from App Bundle is from Play. You can provide a link to any version you published that they can open directly on their device. If you meant *sideloading* APKs generated from App Bundle, then it is not easy for the average users since that will require running a command line tool (bundletool).

Answer (score 0):

Your best option in this situation is to create an Internal Test track in Google Play console, and invite the user in as an internal tester.  Upload your debug bundle into the Internal Test track, and using Bundle Explorer you can copy the direct build URL and share that with the user.

They will need to opt in to your beta program first, and "join the beta" on your app's Play Store listing.